# TextView.setText() followed by TextView.invalidate() doesn't update text in view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have no idea why this doesn't work. The TextView is defined from an  tag in the view. The base TextView doesn't have text set and I want to set it in the View on display.

I have tried placing the below in onCreate and onStart but it doesn't seem to work. The last two lines are just for debugging. I can verify that the header does get the text. The thing is, the TextView doesn't actually get updated. Any ideas?

```
TextView header=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.acheader);
        header.setText(R.string.accounts);
        header.invalidate();
        header=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.acheader);
        String blah=(String) header.getText();
```

Comment: I believe `header.invalidate();` is not needed here. Probably post your `TextView` declaration in the layout xml?

Comment: It turns out that the problem was not the Java code but a misinterpretation of how to use merge and include. Basically, if you include a bit of layout whose root is a <merge> tag, you can't override the id via the <layout > tag. So i wasn't actually pulling the right TextView. I found this out via the hierarchy viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Try again removing the text in 4th line
        header=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.acheader);

Answer (score 0):

1. header.invalidate() is not needed.
2. Instead of String blah = (String) header.getText() try 
      String blah = heager.getText().toString();

And why are you verifying a "setText()" on text view using code? Why can't you check the 
actual output?

The above code might not work the way you are trying to use it, because the redraw of text view is handled by the framework and generally it tries to group item updates (Dirty rectangles to be specific) and update them all at once. It may do it well after your function exits, Try to validate visually, thats the best way.

Comment: I did look at the View visually. The point of checking in code was to see where the failure was occuring. Also, .toString() vs. a cast is just personal pref IMO, its being cast by the toString method from the internal char[].

Comment: but a TextView's text can also be a Spannable with decorations, so it isn't always an 'internal char[]'